# Can't set up virtualenv python: No module named pip

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to set up a python environment on a remote computer via ssh (with no root access). I am following the instructions below:

1. Download the virtualenv script:
        wget -O /tmp/virtualenv.py https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py
2. Run the virtual env script

   ```
   python /tmp/virtualenv.py $HOME/pyenv/
   ```

which will setup the environment in the "pyenv" directory in your $HOME space

3. Update the environment

If you are using bash (I hope you do), then you should add:

```
    . $HOME/pyenv/bin/activate

     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/ioa//lib:/usr/local/lib64       
    to your .bashrc
```

And when I run         python /tmp/virtualenv.py $HOME/pyenv/, I am getting the error

```
New python executable in /home/lht26/pyenv/bin/python
Cannot find a wheel for setuptools
Cannot find a wheel for pip
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
Complete output from command /home/lht26/pyenv/bin/python - setuptools     pip wheel:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pip
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/virtualenv.py", line 2328, in <module>
main()
File "/tmp/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
File "/tmp/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
download=download,
File "/tmp/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
File "/tmp/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/lht26/pyenv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel   failed with error code 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: Whatever python you have installed there does not have pip, it looks like. Which version is it? Why can't you use the system installed python?

Comment: From what I have understood, the python packages installed are too old, and I'll be needing more packages anyway, so it is suggested to use the virtual environment.

Comment: Yes, but you misunderstood my point. Virtualenv can't be installed because the Python on your system does not have pip. I'd suggest you try Miniconda anyways http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

Comment: These comments are not correct.  The error would suggest that, but I have the same problem and have pip for both versions of python installed (2.7 line and 3.6).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to run virtualenv.

First, install pip (pip3 if you have 3 version of python):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then run the following:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv

mkdir myproject
cd myproject
virtualenv venv

. venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: Question said that there's no root access

Comment: I have the same issue, following this steps makes no improvement, error is the same.